# How to redirect from a node controller?

Tags: node.js, express, webdav

I'm working on a project and need to redirect from within the controller to another URL. The project involves the user clicking on a link and a file transfer being performed that results in a url that the user must go to to download the file. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
exports.download = function(req, res, next){
  var downloadId = parseInt(Math.random() * (10001) + 10000);
  while(fs.existsSync("/path/to/local/directory")){
    downloadId = parseInt(Math.random() * (10001) + 10000);
  }
  var path = "/path/to/file/in/server";
  var fileName = clearPath(path); // converts path into just filename
  fs.mkdirSync("/path/to/local/directory/" + downloadId);
  var ws = fs.createWriteStream("/path/to/local/directory/" + downloadId + "/" + filename);
  var rs = ocUser.createReadStream("/path/to/file/in/server");
  var file = rs.pipe(ws);
  file.on('finish', () =>{
    var data = "https://domainname.com/tmp/" + downloadId + "/" + fileName;
    res.redirect(data);
}
```

In the actual code, there are a ton of comments that show what is happening. In that code, console.log(data) within file.on('finish') does nothing. If needed, I can also have it 'res.render' a page that redirects via jquery.

Note: ocCloud represents a webdav instance

Comment: @TGrif ocUser refers to an OwnCloud server. It's a webdav instance

Comment: not exact match but if you want to render html containing the file object and a link for download here's an example : https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs/blob/master/examples/example_simple_exportwav.html#L67